# Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol

Tags: clojure, redis

I have the following clojure code (trying to write / get entries from redis):

```
(ns hello.core2)
(ns h hello.core2 (:require [taoensso.carmine :as car]))

(def pool (car/make-conn-pool))
(def spec-server1 (car/make-conn-spec))
(defmacro wcar [& body] `(car/with-conn pool spec-server1 ~@body))`

(defn -main
  (wcar (car/ping)
    (car/set "foo" "bar")
    (car/get "foo")))
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
    at clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom(RT.java:487)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:468)
```

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably this:

```
(ns h hello.core2 (:require [taoensso.carmine :as car]))
```

There should be only one namespace declaration, like this (so also move the first ns expression):

```
(ns hello.core2
  (:require [taoensso.carmine :as car]))
```

Answer (score 7):

`(defn -main ...)`: you forgot the argument vector for the function `-main`; it should be `(defn -main [& args] ...)`.

Comment: Cheers, can only have one correct answer but this was an issue as well.